# Twitter Bootstrap Dialog shows "2 times"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am building my website using Twitter Bootstrap. I found that my dialog shows "2 times". Here is a video for you if you don't know what am I talking about(expire in 7 days).
[Watch this video](http://wikisend.com/download/131256/twitter.mp4)

Note: I only clicked the Close button one time. You can see there is a dialog appeared about I clicked Close and it disappeared in less than 1 second.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contactModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Contact</h4>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="modelText">Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My button calls JavaScript.

`<button onclick="submitForm()" type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>`

My JavaScript

```
$('#contactModel').modal('show');
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in demo?

Comment: I am not sure how to use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your button's code, but I guess you've been using the bootstrap modal in both ways : via data attributes and via js.
Choose one. Look here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals in "Usage".

Anyway, if it's not the button, then your code works well. here is a proof: http://www.bootply.com/eYXtmm6Yrr.

Comment: The model isn't shown by default. After I clicked a button, my JavaScript did an action and the model is finally shown.

Comment: Pls show your button code. I think you did'nt understand my answer.

Comment: I see, but this isn't the button which opens the modal, it has a different event "onclick" on him. where is your js line from above running? on what event?

Comment: JS line from above running? On what event? I am quite new to web development. I am not sure what are you talking about :\

Comment: $('#contactModel').modal('show'); this line is causing the modal to open. When is it happening? It depends where you put this line. If you attach it to an event, like a button click, then the modal opens on click. Shortly, your code from above doesn't show any problem (like you can see in the link in my answer). So I assume you have to give more information and more code.